# Уничтожить объект класса в Phaser TypeScript

Tags: html5, typescript, phaser-framework

Разрабатываю игру на движку *Phaser* на *Typescript*.
В `State` создаю объект класса, который не наследуется от `Phaser` классов. И не могу убить его в `shutdown()`.
Таким образом, при множественном  рестарте `state` образуется куча объектов этого класса, что завешивает мобильный браузер.

Как корректно сделать это?

```
    module MyGame {
    export class Level_01 extends Phaser.State {
        buttonRELOAD;
        preload() {        }

        create() {           
                this.buttonRELOAD = new Buttons(this.game, 'Reload', undefined, undefined, 'RELOAD');
                Game.ButtonEnabledTime++;
                var DEBUGText = this.game.add.text(23, 150, 'BUTTON_ENABLED: ' + Game.ButtonEnabledTime + ' Time', { font: "36px Arial", fill: "#73fe7f", align: "center" });
                this.game.state.restart(true, false);
        }

    }
    update() {        }
    shutdown() {
          //my tryes
       //this.buttonRELOAD.pendingDestroy = true;
       //this.buttonRELOAD.destroy(true);
       //this.buttonRELOAD.DestroyButton();
       //this.buttonRELOAD = undefined;
       //this.buttonRELOAD.destroy();
       //this.game.world.remove(this.buttonRELOAD);
    }
}
```

}

```
module MyGame {
export class Buttons {
    x: any;
    y: any;
    constructor(game: Phaser.Game, Name: string, x: any, y: any, GoTo: String) {
        this.game = game;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.GoTo = GoTo;
if (Name === 'Reload') {
     x = 50; 
 y = 50; 
            let overButtonReload = function () {
              this.mm_button_enter.play();
            }

            let outButtonReload = function () {
            }
            let actionOnClickButtonReload = function () {
                   Game.StateAdd(this.GoTo); //my game state
            }
            ButtonReload = this.game.add.button(x, y, 'button_reload', actionOnClickButtonReload, this, '1.png', '1.png', '2.png', '1.png'); 
            this.ButtonReload = ButtonReload;
            ButtonReload.scale.setTo(1, 1);
            ButtonReload.onInputOver.add(overButtonReload, this);
            ButtonReload.onInputOut.add(outButtonReload, this);

   }
    public DestroyButton() {
        //this.ButtonReload.pendingDestroy = true;
        //this.game.world.remove(this.ButtonReload);
        this.ButtonReload.destroy(true);
        this.ButtonReload = null;
        console.log(this.ButtonReload);
    }
}
```

}

После главного меню я стартую этот стейт. в нем порождаю кнопку создавая её в другом классе.
Для тестирования автоматически перезагружаю этот стейт. на 150 й попытке ломается звук( наверное из-за переполнения памяти) , а на 300й где то все виснет.
Вывожу дебажный текст что бы увидеть сколько попыток перезагрузки прошло.

Comment: Добавте прямо в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: пробывал destroy(); destroy(true), =null; ничего не помогает. экземпляр живет и загружает память.

Comment: Вы не можете добавить код? Может вы временно на телефоне или ещё какие то сложности?

Comment: @0xdb, да был временно далеко от компа. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: эм, `let obg = {
 name:'qwa'
};
let lin = obg;
console.log(lin);
setTimeout(() => {
 console.log(lin);
}, 1e3);
lin = void(0);
console.log(lin);`